# PHP Regular expression to find string enclosed in __("STRING_TO_EXTRACT")

Tags: php, regex

Sorry I really suck at regexp. I need to collect all the string on my application which are enclosed in this example: __("STRING") the string may be enclosed in single quote as well.

I tried it with the following code:

```
$str = "__('match1') __("match2") do_not_include __('match3')";

preg_match_all("/__\(['\"](.*)['\"]\)/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

but it is only able to match the entire line string with 1 match. Example result below. Please help me edit the regexp so it should be able to get the 3 matches.

```
match1') __("match2") do_not_include __('match3
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = "__('match1') __(\"match2\") do_not_include __('match3')";
preg_match_all('/__\(([\'"])(.*?)\1\)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

`([\'"])` will match either single or double quote and capture it in group #1.

`.*?` will match 0 or more characters (non-greedy)

`\1` is back-reference of above captured group to make sure string is closed with same quote on RHS.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => match1
    [1] => match2
    [2] => match3
)
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks for your help. But seems the pattern you give is still missing something because its only able to capture the first match. https://regex101.com/r/tY8eH4/1

Comment: And the most important part: The lazy "*?" that prevents a match that starts with the first "(" and ends with the last ")"

Comment: I only needed to add the /g in the pattern. thanks for your help anubhava. https://regex101.com/r/tY8eH4/2

Comment: @JohnGarcia: You're missing `g` (global) flag in your demo. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY8eH4/3)

Comment: You don't need the "g" if you use preg_match_all (like @anubhava did)

Comment: @Amarnasan: Yes indeed it is important to use `.*?` to make it non-greedy.